# Get data from Listview? How?

Tags: java, android, database, listview, android-listview

I have a database (db) from I get values (name, email address, phone number. etc) which I put in a list and displayed in a ListView. If I click on an item can I get the whole data from clicked item? Because I need ex. email address to send email. Can I extract from the item the data, because when get data from database is in a "Client" type.

```
List list = db.getAllClients();

    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_ID);
    listview.setClickable(true);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(listview);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view,
                int position, long id) {

                            // some code


        }
    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259960/get-data-from-listview-when-clicking-listviews-child

This answer might help

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you intend to do: when you click a row, what do you need? get just the mail? get all the data? what do you want to do with it? show a contextmenu? execute an action...?

Comment: On a long click pop up a context menu with options Call, Send email to selected item and I need to send email ex to the client on selected ListView item, but I need those data (mail address, phone number, etc). How can I invoke this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to extract your data from your `ListView` per se, only the `Array` that you used to populate your list.

Since `onItemClick(...)` gives you the `position` of the clicked item, you can either...

- Use your `ArrayAdapter` to get the item:

  `adapter.getItem(position)`
- Get your data from your original list:

  `list.get(position)`

In either of these cases, since you are retrieving your data from an anonymous inner class (your `OnItemClickListener`), the `adapter` or `list` in question needs to be an instance variable and not a local variable (i.e. define the `adapter` or `list` as part of your class, above all of your methods).

Answer (score 1):

You can get data from `ArrayAdapter` by position in your `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`:

```
((ArrayAdapter) listview.getAdapter()).getItem(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can see your code , you get List of object `List<Client>`  so

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view,
            int position, long id) {

                       Client client = list.get(position) ;


    }
});
```

because the position refer to the selected index of your list